# TypeError ("unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'instance' and 'float'"

Tags: python, zope

I am using python/Zope for development.
Currently i'm formatting a date object to the format "%m-%d-%Y" in one of files. The code is shown below

```
if resultSet :
   for eachResult in resultSet :
      DateTime(eachResult['txntime']).strftime("%m-%d-%Y")
```

This is triggering the following error:

```
 File "Script (Python)", line 37, in CronJobFindUnmatchedTransfer_v2_1

 File "/opt/zope-2.7/lib/python/DateTime/DateTime.py", line 750, in __init
   s,d = _calcSD(t)
 File "/opt/zope-2.7/lib/python/DateTime/DateTime.py", line 331, in _calcSD
   d = dd / 86400.0
```

I didn't have any idea on this. Somebody please help me out..

Comment: Your traceback is incomplete and looks like it was picked from the wrong place. Is there no error in your Zope log to copy?

Comment: Thanks for commenting.Actually this happens in the production environment.I have no access to the production environment. In my development environment its working fine.

Comment: Even your production environment surely has a more complete traceback in the logs? At least deploy the change I proposed in my answer to the production server to get a handle on what value is being passed into the `DateTime()` constructor to make it fail.

Answer (score 4):

You are passing a value into the `DateTime()` constructor that is *not* supported by that class. What you are passing in is unclear though.

In Zope, when it reports a traceback for an exception (writes it to the log, passes it to the error view), it includes any local variable with the name `__traceback_info__` when printing each stack. This is used to include debug information in the logged exception.

Use this to track what values you are passing to `DateTime()`:

```
if resultSet:
   for eachResult in resultSet:
      __traceback_info__ = (eachResult['txntime'],)
      DateTime(eachResult['txntime']).strftime("%m-%d-%Y")
```

Run Zope in foreground mode (`bin/instance fg` or `zopectl fg`, depending on what version you have and how it was installed), and watch for the traceback being dumped to stderr. It'll have an extra line with the value of `eachResult['txntime']` included in the traceback.